# What is the meaning of それで in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 彼女が好きだから、僕に嫌がらせをしたんだ？僕が彼女を取ったように見えたの？**それで**彼女を巻き込んでたら、意味ないだろう。

Is it "then" or "because of this"?

Comment: I often see soredemo too それでも, but unfortunately I don't know what it means

Comment: `Is it "then" or "because of this"?` >> It's the latter: "because if this", "because of that reason"

Answer (score 3):

I think that in this sentence it would mean "In that case...."

"In that case If I became involved with her, there is no meaning to it"

Hence, the "in that case..." for the last portion of the passage.

**Edit**: Removed theory on what the context was since apparently some others have a more complete picture of the dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

> 彼女が好きだから、僕に嫌がらせをしたんだ？ 僕が彼女を取ったように見えたの？ それで彼女を巻き込んでたら、意味ないだろう。

I hope the OP can confirm at least one of the following two "theories".

1. 僕に嫌がらせをしたんだ？ <-- The OP made a small error in copying this part (from a manga?).
2. my proposed reading is the following.

The speaker S is saying to D (the Dummy guy) --

- Did you pull that trick on me because you were in love with her?  Did you think that i was taking her away from you?
  Your scheme wouldn't  work if it got her involved (if it ends up bothering her) -- Now, would it?

Maybe this is one of those usage instances, where it's  impossible to determine exactly what this それで refers to. ( i.e., Even if we had complete information, we couldn't determine it. )

But if i had to spell it out, it would be like this:  それで == [while carrying out that scheme] ( As a result of your little trick )

それで == [(while) in the process of doing that]  ---

それで == [ As a result of doing that ]  --- It's like 　それをして、それをやって、それをした結果

I'd certainly be interested in real or made-up samples of this usage of  それで -- Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think それで means "then".

彼女が好きだから、
You like her,

僕に嫌がらせをしたんだ？
that is why you are harassing me?

僕が彼女を取ったように見えたの？
It looks like I took her from you?

それで彼女を巻き込んでたら、意味ないだろう。
Then, if she gets involved (in your harassment and then gets hurt), it makes no sense (because it would backfire, you would hurt the person you like).